# Is the number of spin states necessary in the density of states function?

Tags: quantum-spin, field-theory, phase-space, degrees-of-freedom, density-of-states

I'm studying how to calculate the density of states in the final configuration in order to apply Fermi golden rule.
For free EM field the following expression is the starting point:
$$d^3n=\frac V {(2\pi\hbar)^3}d^3P$$
while for non-zero mass particle this expression is the starting point:
$$d^3n=\frac V {(2\pi\hbar)^3}d^3P(2S+1)$$
where $S$ is the spin number and $2S+1$ are the different spin states.
Can you explain me in which cases and why it is necessary to write the $2S+1$ factor in the formula? To me it looks strange that in one case we don't write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is that the second expression includes spin degeneracy, i.e. the number of states which have the same energy. As you probably know, for a given principal quantum number $s$, which determines the magnitude of the spin vector, there will be $2s+1$ possible projections of this spin which give the same energy (usually on the $z$ axis). Normally, in quantum statistics, you want to assume there is spin degeneracy and is sometimes written as a function $g$ so it's simpler to write.

Sometimes it is easier to think in statistics  on whether your system has distinguishable or indistinguishable particles, if you have to apply Pauli's exclusion principle, etc.